# JAXB - A message body writer for Java class was not found

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I am trying to interrogate a rest service, and I need to put some data.

The code I want to use to make the call is the following:

```
WebResource resource = this.client.resource(url);
DocumentIndexFields myDocumentIndexFields = (DocumentIndexFields) resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).put(DocumentIndexFields.class, documentIndexFields);
```

My resource representation is the following:

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for DocumentIndexFields complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="DocumentIndexFields">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="Field" type="{http://dev.docuware.com/schema/public/services/platform}DocumentIndexField" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DocumentIndexFields", propOrder = {
    "field"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    UpdateIndexFieldsInfo.class
})
public class DocumentIndexFields {

    @XmlElement(name = "Field")
    protected List<DocumentIndexField> field;

    public List<DocumentIndexField> getField() {
        if (field == null) {
            field = new ArrayList<DocumentIndexField>();
        }
        return this.field;
    }

}
```

When I execute the call I get the following error:

```
oct. 13, 2014 4:33:58 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl <init>
Grave: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/xml ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General

Exception: A message body writer for Java class myPackage.platform.DocumentIndexFields, and Java type class myPackage.platform.DocumentIndexFields, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
```

Where am I wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Can you post the web service that receives the request? It seems that it doesn't have a [@Consumes("application/xml") annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrpv/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the webservice